# Locale sensitive character classes in regexp with validations?

Tags: regex, validation, ruby-on-rails-3

```
validates_format_of :first_name, :with => /\A\w+\Z/
```

The validation doesn't pass if there are non-english character in first name, like `Mölläinen`. Changing Rails locale doesn't help. So how do you do culture/locale sensitive validation then?

If the locale is `EN`, then `\w` should map to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, but if it's `FI`, then it should map to `[a-zA-Z0-9_äöåÄÖÅ]` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Try `/\A[[:alpha:]]+\Z/`. This should be locale aware, at least in Ruby 1.9.

But you might want to allow other characters too. `Anna-Lena` is a common name in Germany, for example.