# Testing for word characters in Ruby/Rails regular expressions for all languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, unicode, utf-8

I know I can match a word character with `\w` in Ruby's regular expressions:

```
2.0.0p247 :003 > /[\w]+/.match('hi')                                                                                                                                               
 => #<MatchData "hi">
```

However, as I understand, that only matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. I'd like to also match characters that appear in standard words in other languages. Is there an easy way to do this?

***UPDATE***: Seems like I may have found my answer in the POSIX bracket expressions:

```
/[[:alnum:]]/ - Alphabetic and numeric character
/[[:alpha:]]/ - Alphabetic character
```

Is this what I'm looking for?

Comment: Could you provide an example of a standard word in other language?

Comment: @Bala - Hello in Finnish: Päivää

Comment: @at. it is, post that as an answer :)

Comment: There's also the `\p{Alnum}` version if you prefer that syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Definitely on the right track with `:alpha:` Here's a locale aware example from (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3879835/499581):

```
/\A[[:alpha:]]+\Z/
```

also for certain punctuation consider using:

```
/[[:punct:]]/
```

[more here](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt).